# Looking for an efficient way to combine lines in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to aggregate strace output lines on a Linux host. When strace runs with the "-f" option it will intermix system calls line so:

```
close(255 <unfinished ...>
<... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
<... close resumed> )       = 0
[pid 19199] close(255 <unfinished ...>
[pid 19198] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 19199] <... close resumed> )       = 0
```

I would like to iterate through the output and combine "unfinished" lines with "resumed" lines. So in the output above the following two lines:

```
close(255 <unfinished ...>
.....
<... close resumed> )       = 0
```

Would be combined into:

```
close(255) = 0
```

I was thinking about splitting the "unfinished" lines at ">" and putting that into a list. If a future line contained resume I would iterate through this list to see if the system call and pid are present. If they are I would split() the line at ">" and combine the two. Curious if there is a better way to do this?

*** Update ***

Thanks for the awesome feedback! I came up with the following and would love to get your thoughts on the code:

```
holding_cell = list()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    strace_file =  open(sys.argv[1], "r")
else:
    strace_file = sys.stdin

for line in strace_file.read().splitlines():
    if "clone" in line:
        print line
    if "unfinished" in line:
        holding_cell.append(line.split("<")[0])
    elif "resumed" in line:
        # Get the name of the system call / pid so we  can try 
        # to match this line w/ one in the buffer
        identifier = line.split()[1]
        for cell in holding_cell:
            if identifier in cell:
                print cell + line.split(">")[1]
                holding_cell.remove(cell)
    else:
        print line
```

Is there a more pythonic way to write this?  Thanks again for the awesome feedback!

Comment: Why not to read it line by line, when you see an unfinished line keep it in separate buffer else write your buffer, when you see a finished line corresponding to that unfinished line than combine it and write it and clear the buffer, This way you could manages multiple unfinish/finish blocks

Comment: That's actually what I'm currently doing now. My apologies for not clarifying that point.  I'm mostly curious what types of buffer options are available and how to efficiently match up the two.

Comment: You should not post your solution inside the question. If it is sufficiently different from the answer given, post it as an answer on its own. If this is derived from tdelaney's code, accept his answer. Code review - discussing how working code could be written better - is best asked on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

Some iterators such as file objects can be nested. Assuming you are reading this from a file-like object, you could just create an inner loop to do the combining. I'm not sure what the formatting rules for `strace` logs are, but nominally, it could be something like

```
def get_logs(filename):
    with open('filename') as log:
        for line in log:
            if "<unfinished " in line:
                preamble = line.split(' ', 1)[0].strip()
                for line in log:
                    if " resumed>" in line:
                        yield "{}) = {}\n".format(preamble,
                            line.split('=')[-1].strip())
                        break
             else:
                 yield line
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome feedback.